# Holomorphically separable homogeneous space

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, several-complex-variables

Let $X:=G/H$ be a complex homogeneous space. If we are given that the orbits of $X$ acting as a group of holomorphic transformations on a projective space $\mathbb CP^n$ are holomorphically separable and $\mathcal  O(X)=\mathbb C$. How to show that $H$ is discrete?

Comment: Are your stated hypotheses correct? "Holomorphically separable" means holomorphic functions separate points (i.e., if $x$ and $y$ are points of $X$, there exists a holomorphic function $f$ on $X$ such that $f(x) \neq f(y)$); "$\mathcal{O}(X) = \mathbf{C}$" implies all holomorphic functions are constant. If both conditions are true, $X$ is a point, which certainly does not imply $H$ is discrete.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, yes you are right. I edited my question so that the orbits are holomorphically separable.

Comment: The question still makes no sense: $G/H$ is not a group unless $H$ is normal. What do you mean by an action of $X$ in $CP^n$? Also, $CP^n$ has only constant holomorphic functions; what do you mean by "holomorphically separable"?